# print ouputs pink text

Tags: python, rich

I am using the python library "rich" to print text.
If I print with the default style, the text is printed to the console white on black as it should be. But if you print the word "wordn(" for example, it will get printed pink. Basically whenever you print an "n" followed by an "(", it will be printed pink together with everything before until there is a space.
Code Example:

```py
from rich.console import Console
Console().print("wordn(")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `highlight=False` (docs [here](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/highlighting.html))

Comment: Oh yeah, lol I didn't knew that, thanks a lot